# Rails : No route matches when I override the default id in model and use a named route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, routes, named

My Ruby version: ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i386-mingw32]
My Rails version: Rails 2.3.11

The error I am getting is:

```
No route matches "/hcfcdsensors/4513.0/show_graph_hcfcd" with {:method=>:post}
```

Here are my Models

```
class Hcfcdsensor < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_primary_key :device_id
    has_one :hcfcdsensorvalue
    has_many :hcfcdraindatas
end

class Hcfcdsensorvalue < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :hcfcdsensor
end

class Hcfcdraindata < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'hcfcdraindata'
  belongs_to :hcfcdsensor
end
```

My Routes are :

```
 map.resources :hcfcdraindatas
 map.resources :hcfcdsensors

 map.show_graph_hcfcd 'hcfcdsensors/:device_id/show_graph_hcfcd', :controller => 'hcfcdsensors', :action => 'show_graph_hcfcd'
```

The  link_to_remote statement is:

```
<%= link_to_remote "show" , :url => show_graph_hcfcd_url(@hcfcdsensors[0]) ,:update => "graphDiv" %>
```

The "device_id" field is of type double. This route system works fine if I remove the primary key overriding and replace the ":device_id" in route with ":id"

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Shaunak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `.0` part of your path is confusing the routing engine. Usually periods are not allowed in the `:device_id` component because it is employed as a delimiter.

What you can do is replace the offending `.` in your number with something else through string substitution, or use values that are multiplied by a scaling factor to achieve the required precision. For instance, if you need three decimal places worth of precision, use:

```
show_graph_hcfcd_url((@hcfcdsensors[0] * 1000).to_i)
```

When reading the parameter, convert back down:

```
hfcd = params[:device_id].to_f / 1000
```

It may be handy to define a constant in the relevant controller to represent that scaling factor and avoid having hard-coded magic numbers of that sort.

Comment: Thanks tadman. That worked perfect! indeed the .  was confusing the routing engine.

Answer (score 0):

Why is `device_id` a `double`? Is it a legacy database? Even so, I don't know why anyone would use a `double` for a primary key.

You should change it to an `integer`.

If you can't do that, you should add the following method to `Hcfcdsensor`.

```
def to_param
  primary_key.to_i.to_s
end
```

Comment: Yes its a Double and no its not a legacy database, but a database representing legacy ids assigned to sensors on field. But is there a good reason why cant primary key be double? especially when this table doesn't grow.

Comment: I think Austin's referring to the fact that doubles are notoriously fussy and some values are impossible to represent precisely, always ending up a very near approximation. Where you can, use fixed place `NUMERIC` fields instead of an open-ended float so that precision is properly defined.